# Polygon Collision Detection Android

Tags: android, java, collision-detection, graphics

I am starting to try and figure out polygon collision detection in my Android game. I am currently doing pixel level collision detection and it just seems to be too slow (though it works). I was looking at [this](http://www.physicseditor.de/) tool and it seems like it would be really handy to give me a set of vertices for my images. Does anyone have any ideas about how I should go about implementing this? Basically once I have a list of vertices that form a polygon, how can I detect if polygon A intersects polygon B? I can see that these vertices can be used easily with Box2D but I want to try to do this without Box2D first.

Comment: Box2D is open source and has been ported to Java. Why not see how they do it?

Comment: @ClassicThunder: True haha, I am looking at the source right now. As I expected it seems complicated, but I will continue to see if I can get something out of it. Thanks, I hadn't thought about that. Maybe I should just give in and use Box2D haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Separation Axis Theorem](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html)

Comment: This a really great resource, thanks for posting that.

Comment: Separating Axis Theorem and [GJK](https://mollyrocket.com/849) are both popular choices for convex polygon collisions.

Comment: This is the way I am going to go, I think I can definitely get it to work using one of these algorithms. Thanks a lot!